# Can someone give me an idea of active areas relating to pairing based cryptography, and what they involve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, pairings

Apologies if this isn't the place to ask this question. I'm an undergraduate math student and I've been reading about elliptic curves. I've learned about the Weil and Tate pairings as well as Miller's algorithm. I was hoping someone would be able to give me some information about what's "out there" that I could look at to continue my reading. I've read that there's active research in the problem of building pairing-friendly curves, and also trying to optimize Miller's algorithm for special cases.

Are there any other topics that I should consider looking into? I'm a bit hesitant to dive into the issue of building pairing-friendly curves. It seems very technical and heavy on the math. I like math, but I'd like to get a little taste of computer science if possible.